# passing value to bootstrap model using php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button and I am trying to pass value to a model.Inside button I have name="className" value="CPS210-CompSci-I (4)" button is type submit.

```
     <button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" 
       class="btn btn-info btn-md" name="className" value="CPS210-CompSci-I (4)">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Comment
     </button>
```

I have a model. Inside model I have php $className =$POST['className'];
                   echo "$className";

```
 <div ng-app class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo "Note for $firstname $lastname" ?></h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
               <textarea class="form-control" ng-model="note"
                  placeholder="Here you can write a a note for the student. " id="message" 
                  required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a Goal"></textarea>
               <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
               <label class="light">
            </div>
            <hr>
            <?php $className = $_POST['className'];
               echo "$className";
                         ?>                                 
            <h4>Note Regarding:{{note}} </h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is not happening that you expect to happen?

Comment: you've got `ng-` attributes all over the place. is this an angularjs app? if so, you're values should probably come from the javascript rather than from a php statement

Comment: echo "$className" is not displaying.

Comment: have you tries doing `var_dump($_POST['className']);` to see if it even exists or isn't an empty string?

Comment: The value is not passing var_dump($_POST['className']) returns a null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables are only added to the $_POST array after a form has been submitted. You're page must "refresh" before the array is filled. When the modal triggers and opens a new modal box on the scree, this is not considered a page refresh, therefore the value of the button you clicked is not added to the array.

You either need to put your button inside a form tag, which will trigger the modal to open when the page "refreshes" and the value in that key exists. This would be annoying and defeat the whole purpose of bootstrap modals.

You're other, more likely option, is to use javascript to move the value in the button to the spot in the modal when the button is clicked.

```
$('button[name="className"]').click(function(){
   var className = $(this).val();

   $('#class-name').html(className);
});
```

And edit your modal where you want the class name to this:

```
<hr>
<p id="class-name"></p>                               
<h4>Note Regarding:{{note}} </h4>
```